# Ovirt System Test Results View on web not accessible

Tags: linux, curl, ovirt

https://ovirt-system-tests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general/running_tests/index.html

This page contains the following instructions...

```
Once you've located the engine VM's IP, add it to /etc/hosts followed by the name engine.
NOTE: any other name than engine will not work.
Now, log in to the web-UI at:
URL: https://engine/ovirt-engine/webadmin/
Username: admin
Password: 123
Profile: internal
```

These instructions, do you read them as

A) The input to a curl command?

```
curl --user admin:123 https://engine/ovirt-engine/webadmin/ -v  --insecure
```

or

B) To use the url in a browser

I was thinking B, but that would negate the need to update the hosts file i.e How would the browser know the value of engine?

Either way i cant view them, any ideas?

The error message from the curl for the record...

```
# curl --user admin:123 http://engine/ovirt-engine/webadmin/ -v  --insecure
* About to connect() to proxy 148.87.19.20 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 148.87.19.20...
* Connected to 148.87.19.20 (148.87.19.20) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> GET http://engine/ovirt-engine/webadmin/ HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIz
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: engine
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 502 notresolvable
< Content-Type: text/html
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Length: 2771
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
<
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<!-- FileName: index.html
     Language: [en]
-->
<!--Head-->
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
  <title>McAfee Web Gateway - Notification</title>
  <script src="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/files/javascript/sw.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/files/default/stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<!--/Head-->
<!--Body-->
<body onload="swOnLoad();">
  <table class='bodyTable'>
    <tr>
      <td class='bodyData' background='/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/files/default/img/bg_body.gif'>
<!--Logo-->
<table class='logoTable'>
  <tr>
    <td class='logoData'>
      <a href='http://www.mcafee.com'>
        <img src='/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/files/default/img/oralogo-small.gif'></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Logo-->
<!--Contents-->
<!-- FileName: notresolvable.html
     Language: [en]
-->
<!--Title-->
<table class='titleTable' background='/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/files/default/img/bg_navbar.jpg'>
  <tr>
    <td class='titleData'>
      Host Not Resolvable
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Title-->

<!--Content-->
<table class="contentTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="contentData">
      The Host is not resolvable. Most commonly this is due to mistyping the URL in the browser bar. Please verify the spelling and that the site exists and hit refresh.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Content-->

<!--Info-->
<table class="infoTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="infoData">
      <b>URL: </b><script type="text/javascript">break_line("http://engine/ovirt-engine/webadmin/");</script><br />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Info-->

<!--/Contents-->
<!--Policy-->
<table class='policyTable'>
  <tr>
    <td class='policyHeading'>
      <hr>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='policyData'>
If you believe you have received this page in error, please submit an <a href="https://myhelp.oracle.com/app/answers/answer_view_GA/a_id/94/loc/en_US/g_id/141">Oracle MyHelp
Ticket</a>. If this is an urgent, service impacting issue, please contact the Global Service Desk via telephone: Dial **600
Or Local in-country numbers can be found at <a href="http://my.oracle.com/site/git/1591/2666/index.html">Global Service Desk - Contact Numbers

</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Policy-->
<!--Foot-->
<table class='footTable'>
<hr>
  <tr>
    <td class='footData'>
      generated <span id="time">2019-10-10 13:06:25</span> by inet-hqmc07.oracle.com
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Foot-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
<!--/Body-->
<!-- BLOCKBLOCK_ORACLEPROXY_BLOCKBLOCK -->
</html>
* Connection #0 to host 148.87.19.20 left intact
```

Comment: Yep, that's some help written by a engineer.  I'm sure *they* understood what needed to be done ;-) . But URL `https://engine/ovirt-engine/webadmin/` doesn't contain a "real" web addr. So it is meant to match the word `engine` in your `/etc/hosts` file and use that IP address. As it is clearly displaying something via your web broswer, and as it is an admin function, it is very common for tools running to make available a web interface. I don't think you need to mess with `curl`, but you may need to search the ovirt support sites to see how others have solved this, or raise an issue. Good luck

Comment: Yeah its been tough to interpret

Comment: Arg, realized I misinterpreted some of your posting, which must leaves you confused about my comments. But I still think an entry in your `/etc/host` file will be visible/interpreted by your web brower. What happened when you tried that URL in your web browser (or did I miss that too ?) ;-) Good luck.